# How do I cache other routes for offline browsing?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching, vue-cli-3

I am setting up a Progressive Web App supporting offline browsing.

I have already set up offline browsing for my main route ('domainsample.com/') and it responds 200 even if offline.

But when I navigate to other routes ('domainsample.com/about') I receive a `No Internet Page` error.

Here is a sample I deployed in Heroku the URL: https://pwa-hehe.herokuapp.com

I used Vue CLI 3 to set up the project and Node.js and Express.js to run my dist folder in the server.

```
// server.js
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback')

const app = express()

const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist'))

app.use(staticFileMiddleware)

app.use(history({
    disableDotRule: true,
    verbose: true
}))

app.use(staticFileMiddleware)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/'))
})

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("App now running on port", port)
})
```

```
// manifest.json
{
  "name": "pwa-offline",
  "short_name": "pwa-offline",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "theme_color": "#4DBA87"
}
```

```
// service-worker.js

/**
 * Welcome to your Workbox-powered service worker!
 *
 * You'll need to register this file in your web app and you should
 * disable HTTP caching for this file too.
 * 
 *
 * The rest of the code is auto-generated. Please don't update this file
 * directly; instead, make changes to your Workbox build configuration
 * and re-run your build process.
 * 
 */

importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.3/workbox-sw.js");

importScripts(
  "/precache-manifest.d3f1ce5d8331bddc555348f44cfba9d8.js"
);

workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({prefix: "pwa-offline"});

/**
 * The workboxSW.precacheAndRoute() method efficiently caches and responds to
 * requests for URLs in the manifest.
 * 
 */
self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```

Comment: Where did you define the offline strategy? I see only your web manifest, but no service worker's code.

Comment: Hi, edited the question, I am only using the auto generated service-worker.js from Vue CLI 3, i believe i should make my own?

Comment: May I ask if any of the answers worked, or if you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

There's a simpler solution that doesn't involve using `InjectManifest`.

Simply add this to your `vue.config.js` file:

```js
pwa: {
  workboxOptions: {
    navigateFallback: 'index.html'
  }
}
```

It will automatically add the necessary code to your service worker:

```js
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute(workbox.precaching.getCacheKeyForURL("index.html"));
```

I had the same problem and I found the solution here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/717#issuecomment-382079361

Answer (score 1):

**To anyone who is also using the vue/cli-pligin-pwa and vue-cli 3, I have solved this problem.**

The vue/cli-pligin-pwa does its job in caching your js files for offline use of your web app.

but since you're using a Single Page App, you'll have to set a some kind of fallback.

The request for the page **e.g.(sample.com/about)** will be a navigation request and it will serve the cached page for /index.html

**Source**: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#how_to_register_a_navigation_route

**So what I did is, I made a custom service worker by entering this line of code in my
vue.config.js file**

```
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
    pwa: {
        // configure the workbox plugin
        workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
        workboxOptions: {
            swSrc: 'public/service-worker.js'
        }
    }
}
```

and now, create a **service-worker.js** in your public folder directory, and write up the the generated line of codes from vue/cli-pligin-pwa and add the line :
**workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/index.html');**

```
//service-worker.js

self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});

workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/index.html');

// install new service worker when ok, then reload page.
self.addEventListener("message", msg => {
    if (msg.data.action == 'skipWaiting') {
        self.skipWaiting()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your service worker is not aware of which assets to cache. What is the value of `self.__precacheManifest`? (probably the web manifest file).

You would need to configure workbox in order to have some assets for the `precacheAndRoute` method, as this will instruct the service worker on which files to cache and when. Something like:

```
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([
  '/styles/example.ac29.css',
  '/app/offlinePage.js',
  '/app/offlinePage.html',
  // ... other entries ...
]);
```

Per default a service worker does not know which assets or HTTP responses to cache, therefore we have to define and implement a caching strategy according to our requirements.

I wrote an article about [service workers and the available caching strategies](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f). Have a look at it if you want to deepen the topic.

Comment: hi, i will look in to that article, i believe i also need a bit more research with workbox and service worker before i integrate it in vue.js, thanks!

Comment: If the answer helped you going on or answered your question, you should mark it as resolved. +1 eventually if you learnt something from it.